# Jenkins pipeline, parse csv

Tags: csv, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I've been trying to do a simple parse CSV in a Jenkins pipeline.

My CSV is a simple one consisting of a machine name, its IP address, its subnet mask, its default gateway and its primary DNS server address

so

```
SystemName,IPAddress,Subnet,DefGate,DNS
server1,10.10.10.10,255.255.255.0,10.10.10.1,10.10.10.1
server2,10.10.10.11,255.255.255.0,10.10.10.1,10.10.10.1
```

etc.

My script is just this ( basically want to prove I can read the csv split it by line then split each line on the `,` and echo the individual values out on a line by line basis) :

```
   stage('Parse the CSV') {
        steps {
            script {
                dir ('FolderWhereCSVIsClonedFromGit') {
                    if (fileExists('MyCSV.csv')) {
                        echo ' MyCSV.csv found'

                        readFile("MyCSV.csv").eachLine { line, count ->
                            def fields = line.split(',')
                            for(String item: fields) {
                                println item
                                println ' you are parsing line : ' + count
                                }
                                nodes["line${count}"] = {
                                    node {
                                        echo fields[0] + ': ' + fields[1] + ': ' + fields[2] + ': ' + fields[3] + ': ' + fields[4];
                                    }
                                }
                    }
                    } else {
                        echo ' Machines.csv Not found. Failing.'
                    }
```

...

Each time the code runs it only returns the first line though it is split correctly any subsequent lines are not parsed and printed to the console.

The Jenkins install is a managed service though I can get additional modules/plugins installed it's the not knowing what to ask for which keeps throwing me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known bug: [JENKINS-46988](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-46988)

You can work around this issue like this:

```
readFile("/tmp/MyCSV.csv").split('\n').each { line, count ->
```

Answer (score 5):

A bit late to the party, but for future viewers [`readCSV`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readcsv-read-content-from-a-csv-file-in-the-workspace) makes CSV consumption super easy because it returns it as a matrix:

```
readCSV(file: "/tmp/MyCSV.csv").each { line ->
    line.each { field ->
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I ran it as you have in the answer, and got: ``java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected named arguments``. I then looked up the command (https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readcsv-read-content-from-a-csv-file-in-the-workspace) and realised that the CSV file parameter needs to be named. Maybe I'm working in a different Jenkins environment. Here's what worked for me: ``readCSV file: "/tmp/MyCSV.csv"``

Comment: It used to be the case that a single unnamed parameter implicitly referred to the file parameter. I haven't been using Jenkins for a while now, so I'll update the answer according to your feedback. Thanks!

Comment: I think what happened in this case was that the file parameter became optional, maybe it used to be required in the version of Jenkins that was around when you originally posted. As an optional parameter then it's ambiguous, hence the complaint I got. It's actually an interesting point to consider in general: maybe a Jenkins best practice is to just name all your arguments, always, in case the optional/required status gets changed in a future Jenkins version (it's not something I currently do but maybe I should start!).